# Chart with its ticks in geometric progression

Tags: plotting, logarithmic-scale

I have to render a chart with an axis that has ticks with the following values:

```
250, 500, 1000, 2000, 4000, 8000
```

I first thought it was a logarithmic scale. But then I realized the pattern here is simpler (a tick has the value of the previous tick * 2).

[image: custom scale]

Does this type of scale have its own name, or is it simply a logarithmic scale with a "special" base?

Comment: This is simply a logarithmic scale.  The "base" does not come into the definition of what is a logarithmic scale.  To put it differently, on a logarithmic scale, the values $a^k, k \in \mathbb{Z}$ are equidistant for *any* $a$.  A "base" may only come in for the particular choice of values that you mark with ticks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use base 125:-

```
Table[125^(1 + i Log[125, 2]), {i, 0, 4}]
```

> {125, 250, 500, 1000, 2000}

Answer (score 6):

I hope this is instructive example:

```
g[x_] := Log[2, 2 x/125]
lp1 = LogLinearPlot[g[x], {x, 125/2, 8000}, 
  Ticks -> {Table[125 2^(j - 1), {j, 0, 7}], Automatic }, 
  BaseStyle -> {16, FontFamily -> "Arial"}]
lp2 = LogLinearPlot[g[x], {x, 62.5, 8000}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameTicks -> {Table[125 2^(j - 1), {j, 1, 7}], Automatic }, 
  FrameStyle -> Thick, BaseStyle -> {16, FontFamily -> "Arial"}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
ListLogPlot[#,
   Joined -> True,
   Ticks -> {Automatic, #},
   AxesOrigin -> {Automatic, First@#},
   GridLines -> {Automatic, #},
   PlotStyle -> Red] &[NestList[#*2 &, 125, 10]]
```

[image]

```
ListLogLogPlot[#,
   Joined -> True,
   Ticks -> {Range@11, #},
   AxesOrigin -> {Automatic, First@#},
   GridLines -> {Automatic, #},
   PlotStyle -> Red] &[NestList[#*2 &, 125, 10]]
```

[image]